# Angular2 component definition with additional configuration decoration

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, modularity

I want to pass a provider right to a component.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations:[
        SomeComponent.withProviders([provider1,provider2]),
        AnotherComponent.withProviders([provider1,provider2])
    ]
})
export class NestedModule{}
```

**My question:**
Can I configure my components while defining them in the module like above?

**More information:**

*The reason do I need such a thing:*

- I need to define a value provider at module level.
- The component looks at it's parent component to find say `provider1`
  if it doesn't have one.
- I need to define the value provider at the `SomeComponent`'s module
  level (the `NestedModule`).
- The parent component belongs to another module and it has a provider
  with the same key but with a different value at it's module level.
- I want to declare the value provider in a single place not to
  redefine it for each component.
  Any other solution is welcome.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question to make it clear what part is a question and what are conclusions or statements?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer:Sure.I right did. Is it clear enough Günter? Thank you.