# Make angular2 to look for a provider at module level instead of it's parent component

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

- I need to define a value provider at module level.
- The component looks at it's parent component to find say `provider1`
  if it doesn't have one.
- But I need to define the value provider at module level so that if parent component belongs to another module and it has a provider with the same key but a different value, the child component doesn't use it (And uses the one that has been defined at it's module).

Comment: Please post your code. If a provider is only provided at module level, DI will find it there.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer:The provider is defined at both `child component's module` level and `parent component's module level` (The keys are the same but values are different.) And I expect that the `child component` get it's provider from `it's module` not from it's `parent component`. The codes are longer and more complex than I described here.This question only shows the core issue.

Comment: This is not how DI works. DI looks from the requester upwards towards the root injector (provided by Angular itself and `@NgModules`) and takes a value from the first injector it finds this way.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer:It looks for the provider upwards through the `components` not through `modules`. Can you see what I mean?

Comment: Yes, that's how DI works. Each components injector is the child injector of it's parent components injector. The AppComponents injector is the child injector of the root injector where the modules providers are kept. DI looks upwards and takes the value from the first provider it finds.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer:But I need to make the `child component` to look for it's provider at `it's own module` not at it's `parent component` exceptionally.

Comment: As I said, that's not how DI works. You can make the module lazy-loaded. The `@NgModule` of a lazy loaded module is a child injector of the root injector and DI will find providers registered there before providers registered in non-lazy-loaded modules.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer:This is another way of looking at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43581292/angular2-component-definition-with-additional-configuration-decoration